# Quitar valores desconocidos con columna ID

Tags: r

Tengo dos df. Son los mismos datos pero sin la columna id

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '
         id     col2  col3     col4
         1        NA    NA        NA 
         2        NA    NA        NA 
         3       S       NA         C
         4       NA     NA         C
         5       NA      s        NA 
         6       NA      NA         NA 
         7       S     NA         NA ', header = TRUE)


df2 <- df1[,-1]
```

Quiero quitar todas las filas que tengan valores vacíos.

Para el df2, que no tiene id, puede funcionar lo siguiente:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != ""))

 col2 col3 col4
1    S <NA>    C
2 <NA> <NA>    C
3 <NA>    s <NA>
4    S <NA> <NA>
```

Pero para el df1 no me vale pq la columna id lo estropea.

Tendría que quitar la columna, aplicar lo anterior y volver a meter la columna

El resultado final sería esto:

```
id   col2  col3    col4
3    S     <NA>     C
4   <NA>   <NA>    C
5   <NA>    s     <NA>
7    S     <NA>    <NA>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es similar a lo que realizas.
Pero tienes que usar filter_at().

```
df1 %>% filter_at(vars(col2,col3,col4), any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != ""))
```

En filter_at() tendrías que agregar la función vars() que te permite seleccionar las columnas a cuales se le aplicará el filtro.

también se puedo hacer con expresiones regulares. Esto de seleccionar las variables.

```
df1 %>% filter_at(vars(matches("col")), any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != ""))
```

O incluso, con ínidices.

```
df1 %>% filter_at(vars(2:4), any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != ""))
```